# How to set Net Core application or some data inside as non swappable?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core

I need to store some secure files only in memory without saving on HDD. If I have files as simple byte array it could be saved in pagefile.sys on Windows or swap in Linux.

Even if I encrypt data in memory, that still can get on the hard drive. I don't need security in memory, but I have to be sure that when I turn off my server, nothing is saved on it.

Are there any tools to do this quickly and easily?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid swapping out programmatically.   You can only disable swapping on OS-level, but that will have unpredictable effects.

Comment: Linux has the way to do it - https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock
Winapi too -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-2017
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock